# Save data from activity other than main

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a question. I have an android application in which I use several activities, in addition to the main, in some of these I have forms to record data in a sqlite database. the problem is that when trying to store the information through a button I do not get any response from the application. It does not present any errors but neither does it create the database or execute the method. It's as if he had not pressed the button. I am using Android Studio 3.0.1 and SQLite. Please, I hope you can guide me. Thank you.

I attach the code used in one of the activities for the data registration.

```
/*SQLite class*/
public class SqlDB extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

  private static final int version=1;
  private static final String name="DB_Proyecto";

  public SqlDB(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
    super(context, name, factory, version);
  }

  public SqlDB(Context context){
    super(context, name, null, version);
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Ars (idArs INT PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, NameArs TEXT)");

  }


  @Override
  public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

  }
}
```

/*AddArs class. From this i try insert data in db... */

```
public class AddArs extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

EditText et1;
Button bt1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_ars);

    et1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etNombre);
    bt1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btEnvia);

    bt1.setOnClickListener(this);
}

public void GrabaDatos(){
    String nombreArs = et1.getText().toString();
    SqlDB sqlDB = new SqlDB(this, "DB_Proyecto", null, 1);

    SQLiteDatabase dbase = sqlDB.getWritableDatabase();
    if(dbase !=null){
        ContentValues nuevoRegistro = new ContentValues();
        nuevoRegistro.put("NameArs", nombreArs);

        dbase.insert("Ars", null, nuevoRegistro);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Registro Creado.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.bt1:
            GrabaDatos();
            break;
        /*case by other buttons*/
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Tried debugging with a breakpoint?

Comment: Thanks for answering. In debug the code of the lines 44-51 of the class AddArs, which corresponds to the onClick does not run, but does not skip any errors so in the end I do not know what I should do to solve it.

Comment: Okay...I believe Daniel's answer would solve your issue

Answer (score 1):

You're not referencing the button ID correctly.

The correct ID is `R.id.btEnvia`:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.btEnvia:
            GrabaDatos();
            break;
        /*case by other buttons*/
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I had lost in the id of the button.